# In Palantir Foundry's Workshop, how do I clear the default Workshop variable values I saved earlier?

Tags: palantir-foundry, foundry-workshop

Palantir Foundry's Workshop allows us to save default values for variables using the "save and publish with current variable values as default" button. Can these default values be cleared out or reset?

[image: save and publish with current variable values as default button in Workshop]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just to change the default to something else, you can choose another option and save with current variables - that will not clear the default, just change it.

To reset the default:

1. Go to variables
2. Choose the dependency graph
3. Search for the variable
4. Open Debugger on the top right

[image: Open Debugger]

5. Clear the value

[image: Clear Value]

6. Save again with current variables (which will clear the default)

This is useful if you saved a dropdown list to a value for consistent debugging while developing, and now want to release with the first item in the list, which will chosen by default (if it is clear).

*Note*: Simply using `Save and publish` will still retain the older default value, so above steps are necessary.